# What feature of C++ makes use of JR instructions?

Tags: c++, mips

The MIPS jump register (JR) instruction is frequently found in the binary of C++ code. As a result, what feature in C++ makes use of JR instructions and why does it use these instructions?

Comment: That's not really how languages work. You don't have some kind of simplistic mapping of Feature X causes instruction Y to be used. The language defines what should happen, and the compiler is written to generate machine code in accord with those rules. Why any particular instruction gets used at a particular time is usually a complex matter of what is the most efficient way to implement the various code being compiled. And this stuff gets incredibly complex.

Answer (score 1):

Branch instructions can only be used for cases where the target address is known at *compile time* and is *within a small range* of the current instruction. You can't (easily) use it for branching to an address that isn't known *statically* and must be calculated/loaded at run time, or to jump to a target that's too far away

So here are some examples where `JR` or `JALR` must be used (both are exactly the same except that `JALR` stores the current address to return later):

- **Jumping to arbitrary addresses**: Static branch instructions can't be used to jump to a 32-bit or 64-bit address because the immediate is only 16 or 26 bits long. You need to load the full address in a register and jump with `JR`/`JALR`
- [**Function pointers**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/995714): The function to be called is only known at run time, so obviously you need some way to call it dynamically

  ```
  int Add(int a, int b);
  int Sub(int a, int b);
  int Mul(int a, int b);
  int Div(int a, int b);
  int (*p[4]) (int x, int y) = { Add, Sub, Mul, Div };

  int test_function_pointer(int i, int x, int y) {
      return p[i](x, y);
  }
  ```

  **Functions in [shared libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries)** (*.dll, *.so...) are also unknown to the processes before they're loaded, so if you load those libraries *manually* (with [`LoadLibrary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya), [`dlopen()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)...) you'll also get the addresses to a function pointer and call them with `JR`/`JALR`. Typically a function will be called with `JALR` but if it's at the end of a function and [tail-call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310974/995714) is enabled then `JR` will be used instead

  **[Vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)** in many OOP languages like C++ is also an example of function pointer:

  ```
  struct A {
      virtual int getValue() = 0;
  };

  int test_vtable(A *a) {
      return a->getValue() + 1;
  }
  ```

  [Vtable demo on Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxQQAdUCwutp7DJtx5edFY29kZOLpyKypiq3gwEzMQEvsamUUoqanQJSQQhdo7OggqJyan%2BGWX51oXhxZwAlIqoBsTIHADk1gQA1ACC6OgQPb3MpL2jDo3iAMyyAAz9owwGDiP0YxNTM/PiS6MAsgasG33jk5vTc4vLmwAieABuZ1uXfdd7S/t3fRAAVK5xABWaTcEH3Rq9V4AD22mwAnlC5vdeuIAOzSAZDCarBwTY6sCaPJ5o9H3G4/H6lYgGVQDMm3XrM3pPPDJAxsd69YCYAgANTYBkwEGRs1RC0p33JUv6P1GBEwpQA%2BlQDLQ4nRle4es5Xnh4X04dykVTMT8Wb1iHy2rRekDQXgIRBjaavnKZd8DptFSqnokHOwIP1ev9mDNpUyWdaCLaxgBaObYXkCoUi5EyXqcWUYilLTrNVggTrAzqkUydBZl1DFnRyOS9BStdqYNGSWacMsEYtVxrNADWIFm6IAdABObhjhbAyRTgBswLH6KExe4ZYrVdINc6ZYUIAWpG7lYLpDgsCQaCMrjw7DIFAgl%2Bvt5ARjwrgUwNIVBviuIe4gDg9mWDjWEkCLFp2pCXkYWgEAA8rQrDgcepBYEYIjAOwQGoeysRqE8SrYZgMKxAYioQWWupFihrB4A4xBgXoWAUYexB4EYFHNDQ9BMGwHA8PwgjCKIKD1jIQh0XukDNKgrjZLQe6dPGcGzLuMSaqYEDmBU6SkOYBRhBEASePJOnGUEtAGUUkTRFk8TVGZGTqfJuTJFZ9Q2aUeSOYo1TuUZTQtG0HRcIWxaluW2HbocACSAAKDA8sgyC9MCI7cNCuCECQbYdhMehXjezi5U0vR1jIchdkBzQQBeqCFbe5CUI%2BRUuMgwnAJwnALAe36sL%2B/6AShIG0GBLHQbBCFIdhaEYVhKH4NacQEYpm7EaR5GdJBVHYbR9GMRgXSQQQbEcVtJ7cYwLBYQJAiSEIGGiRV4l7VJopbnJ3iKcpsy9PGZQpr0r7vmpdkaFp2g%2BfptSGQ0pDuCZ3g%2BQjFn%2BXDmR4fZ3n6GkJTOVjbkw9ZJQOTjlS%2BXkaORM0TbBfxYUluuUXFjCAAcc7xnOGXtRhWacCOCwC5l%2BBEMQJX5fVT7FVIsySFC5WyDIVXHn2pCDnOkgC8CCwTuiOuzNwCyzmOc4rp0a6RSh267vuh7VQzkhM1bxbK72zQEX%2B3ggNwQA%3D)
- **[Jump table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48017/995714)** (like in a big switch block)

  ```
  typedef int (*func)(int);

  int doSomething(func f, int x, int y)
  {
      switch(x)
      {
          case 0:
              return f(x + y);
          case 1:
              return f(x + 2*y);
          case 2:
              return f(2*x + y);
          case 3:
              return f(x - y);
          case 4:
              return f(3*x + y);
          case 5:
              return f(x * y);
          case 6:
              return f(x);
          case 7:
              return f(y);
          default:
              return 3;
      }
  }
  ```

  GCC compiles the above code to

  ```
  doSomething(int (*)(int), int, int):
          sltu    $2,$5,8
          beq     $2,$0,$L2 # x >= 8: default case
          move    $25,$4

          lui     $2,%hi($L4)
          addiu   $2,$2,%lo($L4)  # load address of $L4 to $2
          sll     $5,$5,2         # effective address = $L4 + x*4
          addu    $5,$2,$5
          lw      $2,0($5)
          nop
          j       $2
          nop

  $L4:
          .word   $L11
          .word   $L5
          .word   $L6
          .word   $L7
          .word   $L8
          .word   $L9
          .word   $L10
          .word   $L11
  $L11:
          jr      $25
          move    $4,$6

  $L9:
          sll     $4,$6,2
          jr      $25
          addu    $4,$4,$6
  # ... many more cases below
  ```

  You can see the full output on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ1QBXYsg4ByAgE8ADpixUA1HnpGIAKirLayAJQRTBO%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%2B8oQJgtDoIerDKCE8qSN60HoAAMqYmAAHIIeWJYgISpC6KgCiEHgdBwQhSHesRpEQRhtDYbh%2BGES07DjuRtAMAQdYEJRiHmt6bHgZx3G8QxTEhHhxAEYoPHEHxqDwQJyFyeJmE4VJLESpqaj3hKm7Sv6w7KhoACyACSAAKDBGMAyBxFa3DmLghAkDqnCJIeCZJiWHl2EYaoyHI%2BpVhKEBxqEGYluQlDpr5MnIM%2BwCcJwHjhoWnIlmWlY9jWtD7quzahK2BAdl2w59gOQ49vgY4TtOs6KqQ86Lsux5rvQG5bjue71oeWBFae56XgWdCMCwQ4PgIkhCAOr7Be%2B27ll%2BEA/n%2BnGAcBRg/PJwDhEY2a5qB7EQZQqH8fK3CuC1MESZp0kgNkREkWRFFKVRIDXS9dGcfdzEyc9wkcXQYkKZdX03cDEFgwQ/1aYDangx9AnfQo8lwxpANPTpKh6VwBlSjKcomVKyQOj8hLOUlA6zJwloeAzLn4EQxAeV5UUJTqkgBUFsgyKFgbGqQZrZNwlrcISqWuISyKcJIHi2jLPp%2BiTPamSGgiRuKhMaJIxnq8GEZhRK06lpxX1AA)

  `$L4` is a jump table containing the address of the place you're branching to, which is the `case` blocks in this snippet. Its address is stored in `$2` and `jr` needs to be used to move the instruction pointer to that address. `j $2` is shown above but I think it's a disassembler bug, since `j` can't receive a register operand. Once you're at the correct case then `jr` is again used to call the `f` function pointer

See also [Necessity of J vs. JAL (and JR vs. JALR) in MIPS assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41175942/995714)